# Installing TensorFlow in a Virtualenv on openSUSE

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, opensuse

I tried to install TensorFlow in openSUSE12.1. I used virtualenv.

I think TensorFlow is installed. But when I type:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

this error message comes out:

> Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-open.c: 596: _dl_open: Assertion `_dl_debug_initialize (0, args.nsid)->r_state == RT_CONSISTENT' failed!

Comment: which version of Python do you use in your virtualenv ?

Answer (score 1):

openSUSE12.1 is EOL for a long time. The version of TensorFlow you installed is linked against a version of a shared library that can't be found on your system (my guess is it requires a newer version than the one you have).

You should consider upgrading your system to a supported product, the latest point-release version is "Leap 42.3"[1]. That will fix your library issue for TensorFlow and also fix a lot of security issues that your system has right now.

[1] - https://software.opensuse.org/distributions/leap